# Persistent login with Google OAuth2 using the PHP client library

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I've been using the PHP client library for Google OAuth2. I have everything working perfectly, however, when the token expires around 3600 seconds (60 min.), I get an error.

I had it set to when the access token expires, it redirects to the home page; like so:

```
     if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
       session_destroy();
       header('Location: index.php');
     }
```

Works fine, although rather annoying to a user who is logged on and gets logged out 60 min in, trying to use the app.

How can I make the session longer?

Comment: Could you please share the code of the auth somewhere? i am having some problems using oauth and the lib ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2):

> Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access
>   to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can
>   obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to
>   obtain new access tokens.

Example:

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken($token->refresh_token);
    $token = $client->getAccessToken();
    // save the new token
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I was headed in the right direction, just missed a couple things. Thanks for the help!